# Where is the best place to quest at level 88 as Alliance?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I've been looking for a while to find a place to quest at level 88 as Alliance.

Comment: What are you looking for when you say "Best"? Most efficient XP? Most entertaining gameplay? Best zone-wide story?

Answer (score 4):

**I'd say the best Place to level from 88-89 is the Kun-Lai Summit**

Why? Let me tell you:

Recently Blizzard lowered the amount of experience needed from 85 to 90 by a huge amount. So you will reach a higher level than before if you stay in a certain zone for longer than it's actually meant to be. It's also a good thing to continue with these quests although you've already "outleveled" it. Let me explain why:

If you are questing at lower level zones you will gain a little less experience, but at the same time you will do the quests a lot faster. This is especially true for Pandaria. The health of enemies is increasing by a huge amount for every level they gain, but the experience you gain from killing them or doing quests that require to fight them doesn't go up that much. This means you should quest in regions that you actually already are too "high" for.

Another thing are the mobs in MOP. You have the Mogu who have more HP than the average trash mob and The Mantis which are basically the new murlocs (You pull one, you pull the whole map). You should avoid doing quests which require you to kill a lot of Mantis. Of course at some point you will have to do them, but focus on Non-Kill Quests first.

Now with these things said I'd say the best way to level from 85-90 is:

- **85-86 Jade Forest** (Only place to really level, the quests aren't good though)
- **86-87/88 Valley of Four Winds** (The valley has a lot of non-kill quests, Krasarang focusses more on kill quests)
- **87/88 - 89 Kun-Lai Summit** (Huge Zone, A lot of non-kill quests and can also be fun)
- **89-90 Dread Wastes** (You should be half to level 90 if you start here. The Klaxxi help you with their special ability but the quests are really awful. The only reason you should go here is because they actually give way more exp than anything else)

Answer (score 0):

Leveling Zones from Level 85 to 90 are the same for Alliance and Horde:

- 85: Jade Forest
- 86: Valley of Four Winds / Krasarang Wilds
- 87: Veiled Stair / Kun-Lai Summit
- 88: Townlong Steppes
- 89: Dread Wastes

A more detailed list is [here](http://www.wowhead.com/zones=106).